# Do both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 chkdsk commands work?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, chkdsk

like for instance on windows 8.1

```ps
chkdsk C: /f /r /x
```

compared to windows 10's

```ps
chkdsk C: /f /x /r
```

Both commands work right no matter the windows version?

It will not damage the SSD or any of that stuff?
Because I accidentally changed the letters while on command prompt running as administrator.

Comment: The order of the parameters is irrelevant.

Comment: it wont damage my components like my windows drive? where my os is stored?

Comment: in theory if your drive was very near death e.g.  a spinning disk drive suffering from the click of death, then a chkdsk set to repair it, could ruin it.. and it's better to use dd to image it, and testdisk to read the dd image. But aside from that special case, it won't do any harm.

Comment: CHKDSK works essentially the same way going back to DOS.

Comment: in terms of damage, you are fine, albeit with the caveat that if for some reason either of the invocations you present would damage the disk or its filesystem, then both will. a lot of what chkdsk does is comparing the Filesystem metadata to the contents of the disk, and trying to repair anything that is wrong. the problem can come in when there is no way to fix the given issue detected without making a destructive change either to the metadata or the disk contents. So, while chkdsk is working perfectly fine, it doesn't necessarily follow that it will cause no damage.

Comment: Also note that chkdsk will make a event log entry when it completes its scan. if you want to check it, it should tell you if chkdsk did much repairing.  add it to your question if you like.

Comment: I was nervous because i ran chkdsk C: /f /x /r right after i did a chkdsk C: /f /r /x command 

Answer (score 2):

Correct, the command `chkdsk C: /f /r /x` is functionally identical to `chkdsk C: /f /x /r`. The order of the command-line parameters does not matter for chkdsk.

In fact, most command-line applications do not care about the order of the parameters unless the parameters are calling for specific input, i.e., a filepath. But these parameters for chkdsk are used to enable different options, therefore the order won't make a difference. It certainly wouldn't cause any negative effects to your drives.